How to return Errors via GRPC/Protobuf API in Golang with rich information?
I started learning golang, so I built a small API (using GRPC & Protobuf) in my golang application.
The project grew and grew - but now I am at a point, where I don't really know how to continue:
It's the part with returning errors via API. I found out, that the possibilities to return errors using "native" GRPC don't fit what I need, so I started looking around - but nothing was really matching what I am looking for. That's where you come in to place - maybe you have some opinions about that.
Let's say, I have an API, returning some information about image cropping/resizing.
It looks like this at the moment:
message ImageResizerResponse {
  MyPictureType picture = 1;
  MyMetadataType metadata = 2;
}

Now, it might happen, that an error occurs. For now, I just worked with the GRPC Status Codes and some Error Messages. But with growing the project, I wanted to have some more detailed information. I thought about putting a new "error" element in the response, also to make every element optional in the protobuf definition - so that only the error - OR the two "success" objects get returned:
message ImageResizerResponse {
  optional MyPictureType picture = 1;
  optional MyMetadataType metadata = 2;
  optional Error error = 3;
}

message Error {
  uint32 error_code = 1;
  uint32 error_category = 2;
  string error_message = 3;
}

This somehow helps me solve the problem: I want to have some detailed information in my response: An error Code, my error category and a detailed error message. The error_code could be any random number - it is like a "sub error" of the error_category, whereas the category could mean something like "resources exceeded" and the error_code could represent something like "you don't have enough disk space left", "you don't have enough credits left for converting", ...; while the error_message will give me detailed information:
"You tried to pay 5,00$ while you only have a balance of 4,50$" - or "You tried allocating 500MB of data, your Space is only 250MB".
The problem I have with this solution: It leads to having "only optional" parameters in the response, as well as having (from my level of knowledge) only GRPC Codes "success" in the response, but an "Error" Struct in the response.
While my "Error Message" idea helps me solving the problem I have, it feels wrong. On the other hand: Using GRPC Error Codes (and some Error Texts) does not help me at all, because I am not able to represent, what I want to message through the API.
Any thoughts on that? Are there best practices out? Or am I missing any technique?
Thanks!
I tried thinking about the problem: I tried sending a "Message" in the response. I tried using GRPC Status codes.
While my "Error Message" idea helps me solving the problem I have, it feels wrong. On the other hand: Using GRPC Error Codes (and some Error Texts) does not help me at all, because I am not able to represent, what I want to message through the API.
I also stumbled around this:
https://github.com/googleapis/googleapis/blob/master/google/rpc/status.proto + https://github.com/googleapis/googleapis/blob/master/google/rpc/error_details.proto - but it did not help me.

Have a look at Error handling
